# Different way int n can be split in groups of 1 or 2

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, combinatorics

This is the question posed to me for an assignment:

> A patient has n pills to take. In each day, he can take either one
>   pill or two pills until all pills are gone. Let T(n) denote the number
>   of different ways the patient can take all n pills. Give a closed form
>   for T(n). (Note that – for example – the two sequences (1, 2, 2) and
>   (2, 1, 2) are considered as two different ways of taking 5 pills.)

I have tried to work the sets for n = 1 through 8 to see if I can find a pattern like so:

> n=1 {1} n=2 {{1,1},{2}} n=3 {{1,1,1},{1,2},{2,1}} n=4
>   {{1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{2,2}} ...

But haven't been able to.  Combinations from n=1-8 are 1,2,3,5,8,12,18,25

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows wrong values after 8 (should be 13...).

Consider the next approach: in the last day patient can eat the one pill or two pills (`n = (n-1) + 1`  or `n = (n-2) + 2` ). So number of ways to compose T(n) value is

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

Repeat the same process with T(n-1) and T(n-2) and you'll finish at T(0) or T(1) - these values apparently are equal to 1.

So build recurrent sequence and solve recurrence for any n.

Note that you can unwind recurrence from the end (recursion method) and start from the 0/1 - iteration method.

When you find correct values, you might discover that they form famous sequence and read more about  it.

Comment: Yes I had seen the Fibonacci pattern, however what threw me off was that when I continue to build the possible sets, the set of possibilities for n = 6 gave me 12, not 13.

Like so: {{1,1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,2}, {1,1,1,2,1}, {1,1,2,1,1}, {1,2,1,1,1}, {2,1,1,1,1}, {2,2,1,1}, {2,1,2,1}, {1,2,2,1}, {1,2,1,2}, {1,1,2,2}, {2,2,2}}

as you can see, 12 combinations not 13.  Same continues for n=7,8,... 

That's why i dismissed the T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) i had already considered.

Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Missed `{2,1,1,2}`

Comment: Yes you're right.  I kept missing the middle sequences for all my sets.  I did it several times too because I initially saw the Fibonacci pattern.  Wow, now I feel foolish haha.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way to solve this, It becomes very interesting problem when you consider this as a permutations and combinations problem.

Let's take

```
n = 6 as a example,
```

let's say

```
d = number of days patient takes to take all n pills

maximum number of days patient can take those pills are 6. (1 for each day).
minimum would be 3. (2 for every day).

when d = 6 => {1,1,1,1,1,1} 
so when d = 3 => {2,2,2}

when d = 4 => {1,1,2,2}. patient can take this pills in any order in those 4 days. 
so number of combinations are = 4!/2!2! = 4C2.

when d = 5 => {1,1,1,1,2}.
number of combinations = 5!/4!1! = 5C1.

when d = 6 => {1,1,1,1,1,1}. 
number of combinations = 6!/6!0! = 6C0.
```

lets, go back to minimum number of days,

```
when d = 3 => {2,2,2} => 3!/0!3! => 3C3.
```

now you can easily see a pattern here in the factorials,

```
 when d = d => d!/(numberOf1s)!*(numberOf2s)!.
```

so number of different ways 
the patient can take all 6 pills are

```
T(6) = 3C3 + 4C2 + 5C1 + 6C0.
T(6) = 1 + 6 + 5 + 1 
T(6) = 13;
```

according to above pattern here is the algorithm,

```
d_M - maximum number of days;
```

[image]

```
d_m - minimum number of days;
```

[image]

```
T(n) -  number of different ways the patient can take all n pills
```

[image]

This is how you can do it with simple javascript,

```
function numberOfDiffWays(n){

  var dmin = Math.ceil(n/2);
  var dmax = n;
  var sum = 0;

  for(var d= dmin; d<=dmax; d++){
    sum = sum + nCr(d,(2*d-dmax));
  }
  return sum;
}

function nCr(n,r) { 
    return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r)); 
} 

function fact(n) { 
  return n==0 ? 1: n*fact(n-1);
} 

console.log("n=1: " + numberOfDiffWays(1)); // 1
console.log("n=2: " + numberOfDiffWays(2)); // 2
console.log("n=3: " + numberOfDiffWays(3)); // 3
console.log("n=4: " + numberOfDiffWays(4)); // 5
console.log("n=5: " + numberOfDiffWays(5)); // 8
console.log("n=6: " + numberOfDiffWays(6)); // 13
console.log("n=7: " + numberOfDiffWays(7)); // 21
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to compute the fibonacci sequence, although the identity is interesting (and well-known).

Comment: See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297443/prove-the-following-equality-sum-k-0n-binom-n-k-k-f-n

Comment: yep. I agree. but this is a interesting way of looking at the problem. if this involves more than 2 pills or change the conditions of the question it may not be able solved by Fibonacci.

Comment: If the conditions of the problem change in some  unspecified, your solution might not work either. It becomes a completely different problem. However, if the change is simply to change the number of possible increments, then a fibonacci-like recursion still applies, and all such recursions can be solved in O(log N) KxK matrix multiplies (where the matrix size K is the largest possible increment) or in a more straight-forward way with O(KN) additions, simply by iterating the recursive formula.